# Javascript function defined in view.js not reachable from save.js

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I am trying to develop a custom gutenberg block.
I have a form in save.js:

```
export default function save() {
return (
    <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
</div>);}
```

File view.js is defined in block.json ("viewScript":  "file:./view.js",)

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData(event.target);
...
};
```

But when the block renders, it fails.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSubmit is not defined
```

Its all nice if i use "traditional" javascript (e.g. jQuery, console.log), so enqueueing is not the problem.
I am pretty new with "modern" javascript (React, Angular...) and the question is surely pretty dumb, but i am looking for a proper way to coding and not only looking for a functional solution.

Comment: Add `export`  in view.js to export handleSubmit  `export const handleSubmit = async (event) => {` then import handleSubmit in the beginning of save.js page `import { handleSubmit } from './save';`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal:

- All of your React logic will need to be in your **edit.js** file and not your **save.js** file. The **save.js** file is only for viewing the final data on the WP Admin after you save a post or on the live post.
- The **view.js** file can only contain Vanilla JavaScript (from the way you are using it). Then when you save your block, on the saved post WP Admin screen or the live post screen you the React JSX you added in your **save.js** file will be converted to HTML and your **view.js** file will need to be Vanilla JavaScript that interacts with this HTML.

Let em know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! You said `The view.js file can only contain Vanilla JavaScript (from the way you are using it)`. So you mean it is possible to have jsx in view.js? If yes, how? Because I'm using vanilla js and I'm worried about having some possible and unexpected XSS issues there.

Comment: @kodfire
In a WordPress block, the `view.js` file can only have JavaScript with NO frameworks (that's what I mean when I refer to `Vanilla JavaScript`), so it can't have JSX.

The JSX you are referring to is part of React (source: https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx) which can NOT be used in the `view.js` file.